# the best way to use LIKE query in websql.

Tags: sql, web-sql

I have a 2 tables that are old_test and new_test /bible database/

```
old_test table has 7959 rows

new_test table has 23145 rows
```

I want to use LIKE query to search verse from two tables.

For example:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM old_test 
 where text like "%'+searchword+'%" 
union all 
SELECT * 
  FROM new_test 
 where text like "%'+searchword+'%"
```

It works good but taking a lot of time to show the result.

What is the best solution to search much faster on above condition?

Thanks

Comment: which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Thanks Steph Locke. It is WEBSQL

Comment: it will be more helpful if can provide more info like table columns, primary keys and indexes created.

Answer (score 1):

Your query `%searchword%` cause table scan, it will get slower as number of records increase. Use `searchword%` query to get index base fast query.

What you need is full-text search, which is not available in websql.

I suggest my own open source library, https://github.com/yathit/ydn-db-fulltext for full-text search implementation. It works with newer IndexedDB API as well.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your query is that you having to search entire fields segment by segment to find the string using `like` - building an index that can be queried instead should alleviate the problem.

Looking at Web SQL it uses the SQLite engine:

> User agents must implement the SQL dialect supported by Sqlite 3.6.19.

http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#parsing-and-processing-sql-statements

Based on that, I would recommend trying to build a full-text index over the table to make these searches run quickly http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html